# Is perror thread-safe?

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix, posix-api

I know that errno is thread-safe. And in Linux, there are another 2 similar functions, namely strerror and strerror_r. According to the book `Linux System Programming` by Robert Lover, strerror is not thread-safe but strerror_r is. So I am wondering if perror is thread-safe or not.

Answer (score 5):

In POSIX systems (like Linux), `perror` is thread-safe.

`perror` is not listed as non-thread safe here:

> All functions defined by this volume of POSIX.1-2008 shall be thread-safe, except that the following functions1 need not be thread-safe. [...]

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html

Comment: Even better guarantees with C11.

Comment: @Deduplicator indeed if you go with c11, `perror` is guaranteed to be thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from C11 (earlier standards did not acknowledge multi-threading at all):

> #### 7.1.4 Use of library functions
>
> [...]
>   4 The functions in the standard library are not guaranteed to be reentrant and may modify
>   objects with static or thread storage duration.188)
>   5 Unless explicitly stated otherwise in the detailed descriptions that follow, library
>   functions shall prevent data races as follows: A library function shall not directly or
>   indirectly access objects accessible by threads other than the current thread unless the
>   objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the function’s arguments. A library
>   function shall not directly or indirectly modify objects accessible by threads other than
>   the current thread unless the objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the function’s
>   non-const arguments.189) Implementations may share their own internal objects between
>   threads if the objects are not visible to users and are protected against data races.

If none of the arguments to `perror` can be concurrently accessed by other threads (there thus cannot be data-races on them), `perror` is thread-safe, just like all other C11 standard library functions where no explicit exception is listed.

Comment: *just like all other C11 standard library functions* `perror` is but not all are. c11 says *"Unless explicitly stated otherwise in the detailed descriptions that follow, library functions shall prevent data races as follows"* For example, `strerror` c11 says *"The strerror function is not required to avoid data races with other calls to the strerror function"*.

Comment: @ouah: It's always the few words you don't read which are important. Added the possibility of an explicit exception in the functions description for the general case. Thanks for reading that over.